Form is redirecting to script.googleusercontent on submit
I have a simple form on my shopify page;
<div class="form-container">
  <form id="giveaway-form"
  method="POST" 
  action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/MY-WEB-APP-URL/exec"
>
    <div class="form-row">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>

And a script that previously was displaying a pop-up on successful form submission and reloading the page the user is on;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('giveaway-form');
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const action = e.target.action;
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert("Success!");
    })
  });
});

This was working on 9/5 and still does submit the form data into my google sheets, but is now redirecting me to this page on form submission and no longer displays the pop-up telling the user if their submission was successful or not.


That seems unlikely, since the preventDefault() will stop the automatic forwarding. Something else is going on.

When I tested your showing script, alert("Success!"); works fine. And, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this situation. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your whole script if your showing script is not the whole script for correctly replicating your current issue but is now redirecting me to this page on form submission and no longer displays the pop-up telling the user if their submission was successful or not.?

Apart from some additional code to handle a rules modal pop-up on the same page this is all thats in my script code. As I said it was working fine on Friday but now seems to be redirecting the user. The page loads of a little after submission and then redirects with no inidcation or pop-up that the user has submitted the form successfully

With MY-WEB-APP-URL in the URL, this only gets a 404 response - which is likely not helpful in reproducing what actually happens. Can you give us an example we can actually properly test, please? (I am also getting a CORS error when trying your code in a jsfiddle - but I can't currently tell if that is due to the fake example URL.)
